# How to use a class loader to load a jar from my website in a script for a java application

Tags: java, classloader

I am writing scripts for a bot client for a java-based game called Runescape. The scripts follow a basic skeleton and can be saved as jars and loaded in the bot client's script folder.  What I want to do is create one jar file that will load my scripts from my remote folder so that users don't have to update it manually, and it will also give me tighter security.

How might I do this?

The bot scripts have an onStart() method that is called when the script is initiated, so I would have to run the jar at that point.

Comment: "writing scripts for a bot client for … Runescape" oh God…

Comment: The inevitable SO question is: _"What have you tried?"_

Comment: I've tried basic tutorials I've found and nothing is quite working. Maybe I'm not understanding where/when everything should go. @GregKopff

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than _"run the jar"_ I think. Jars have class files in them (and other resources), which are loaded by a class loader.  What is it that you are really trying to do?

Comment: Basically when you start the bot, you have a script selector. The bot automatically detects the right class in the jar (the one that extends Script, their class) and shows it in the selector, without any extra classes/resources. 

Instead of having an ordinary script there, I would like to have a class loader (would have to be in the onStart method of their skeleton) that loads the script in a similar fashion to their script selector. @GregKopff